# Python's Evaluation of If-Else Conditional Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I recently encountered an example of an if-else conditional statement and could not understand the rationale behind its output. The following are the statements:

```
if 0:
    1
else:
    2
```

Output: 2

I tried different integers in 0's place, and received 1 each time. Is this because the zero in the if condition represents False? But then why do integers other than 1 still satisfy the if condition?

Thanks!

Edit: *Thank you for all your answers. I now understand that any integer except 0 in the 'if' statement will make the statement True by default, resulting in an output of 1, in this case.*

Comment: What does `bool(0) is True` give?

Comment: This behavior is pretty common in programming languages, e.g. C, C++

Comment: @cricket_007 It gives False! I Bool(any other integer) is True, gives True.

Comment: Yup. Exactly my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will *always* attempt to determine the "truthiness" of a given value used in a boolean context.  In Python any numerical value of 0 (or 0.0) is considered false, and string, dictionary, list, or other iterable (or other class that can report its length) is false if it's empty or has length of 0.  Also, `None` and boolean `False` are considered false.

Other values are considered true.

More details: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html.

Comment: In Python, `False` is capitalized.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Was answering Python questions while programming in C#!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `bool` is a subtype of `int`. False has the value 0, while other non-zero integers have the subtype `bool` with the value `True`.

To see this for yourself try this: `False == 0`

And to see the subtypes of int try this: `int.__subclasses__()`

Answer (score 0):

1 is considered `True` while 0 is `False`,just like in binary.

Any non-zero numeric value is evaluated as True in a conditional statement.

bool  type is just a subtype of  int in Python, with `1 == True` and `0 == False`.